# Prove $(A \backslash B)'\backslash (B \backslash A) = B \backslash A$

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of some universal set.
Prove that $(A \backslash B)'\backslash (B \backslash A) = B \backslash A$

Given:

Definition 3.3.1 states that $A$ and $B$ are sets. The complement of $B$ relative to $A$, written $A \backslash B$ is the set 
$ A \backslash B =[x:x \in A \land x \notin B]$

Definition 3.3.3 states that $U$ is a universal set and $A \subseteq U$. The complement of $A$, written $A'$ is the set $A' = U \backslash A =[x \in U: x\notin A]$

For B relative to A,

Using Definition 3.3.1

$A \backslash B = [x: x \in A \land x \notin B]$

Using Definition 3.3.3

$(A \backslash B)' = [x : x \in A : x \notin B]$

For A relative to B,

Using Definition 3.3.1

$B \backslash A =[x: x \in B \land x \notin A]$

Using Definition 3.3.3

$(B \backslash A)' = [x: x \in B : x \notin A]$

---

The $\backslash$ can be read as $-$, so the problem may look like this

$( a-b)' - (b-a) = b-a$

I could try to use one of the Propositionals which is $(B')' = B$

Maybe if B = a - b

$((a-b)')' - (b-a) = b-a$

$(a-b) - (b-a) = b-a$

$(a-b)-b+a = b-a$

$a-b-b+a = b-a$

hmmm that's $2a-2b = b-a$

factoring  out the -2 would result in $-2(-a+b) = b-a$

That clearly doesn't equal to b-a.

Is it possible to prove this problem with venn diagrams instead?

I could draw one for $(A \backslash B)'$, $(B \backslash A)$ and $(A \backslash B)' \backslash ( B \backslash A)$

On one diagram, the A would be shaded

On a second diagram, the B would be shaded.

On the third diagram A and B which would be the middle is shaded.

Edit: Maybe a counterexample will work since the left side of the problem could  not have the elements of $B \backslash A$, but the right side does.

Or...

since

$(A \backslash B)'\backslash (B \backslash A) = B \backslash A$

applying definitions. 
$[x : x \in A : x \notin B]' \backslash [x: x \in B \land x \notin A]$ = $[x: x \in B \land x \notin A]$ ???

Edit: I need to provide an improved version of this proof.

Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of some universal set.
Prove that $(A \backslash B)'\backslash (B \backslash A) = B \backslash A$

Given:

Definition 3.3.1 states that $A$ and $B$ are sets. The complement of $B$ relative to $A$, written $A \backslash B$ is the set

$ A \backslash B =[x:x \in A \land x \notin B]$

Here is what I have so far...

$( B \backslash A ) = [x: x \in B \land x \notin A]$

that is the end result. I need to somehow work from the left and achieve $(B \backslash A ))$

$(B \backslash A)' =[x:x \notin B \lor x \in A]$

$(A \backslash B)' =[x:x \notin A \lor x \in B]$

I may have to use the definition again, but it is messy.

Set property by default definition is $A \backslash B = A \cap B'$

so from set intersection definition ...

$ [x: x \in A \land x \notin B]$

since $(A \backslash B)'$....$ [x: x \notin A \lor x \in B]$

/////

set property  $B \backslash A = B \cap A'$

set intersection definition... $[x: x\in B \land x \notin A]$

since $(B \backslash A)'$...$ [x: x\notin B \lor x \in A]$

Edit: Going through the definition is a very bad idea. I've used the set property and was able to get $ B \backslash A$

Comment: As written this can't possibly be true in general. The left set, by definition of $\backslash$, has NO elements of $B \backslash A$, whereas the right IS $B \backslash A$.

Comment: As before, we take benefit of the "correspondance" between set operations ($\cup$, $\cap$) and boolean operations ($\lor$, $\land$), now you can use also the correspondance between *complement in U* and "negation" ($\lnot$).

Comment: I've typed it exactly how the book prints it out.   it seems that $(A \backslash B)'\backslash (B \backslash A) = B \backslash A$
So the left side would state that $B \backslash A$ doesn't have elements, but that would mean that  $(A \backslash B)'$ won't have elements of $B \backslash A $ either.

Comment: In the passage from $A \backslash B=[x:x \in A \land x \notin B]$ using Definition 3.3.3, to $(A \backslash B)′$ you must "negate" the condition defining $A \backslash B$ and this will be : $\lnot (x \in A \land x \notin B)$ i.e. (use DeMorgan laws) : $\lnot x \in A \lor (\lnot x \notin B)$ i.e. $x \notin A \lor x \in B$.

Comment: Crud! I've heard of those Demorgan Laws... they involve switching the $\land$ and $\lor$

Comment: $\lnot (x \in A \land x \notin B)$
for $(A \backslash B)'$ 
So the $B \backslash A$ would be the same like definition 3.3.1
$B \backslash A =[x: x \in B \land x \notin A]$

Comment: Yes : $B \backslash A$ is $x \in B \land x \notin A$, so in order to obtain the *complement in U* we must "negate" the condition. So we have : $(B \backslash A)'$ is $x \notin B \lor x \in A$.

Comment: alright... so umm do we combine $(A \backslash B)' \backslash (B \backslash A)$ so it can somehow equal to $B \backslash A$?

Comment: @Mike I think this should be $$(A \setminus B)' \setminus (B \setminus A)' = B \setminus A.$$

Comment: $\lnot ( x \in A \land x \notin B) \backslash (x \in B \land x \notin A) = (x \in B \land x \notin A)$

Comment: $(B \backslash A)' = \lnot [x: x \in B : x \notin A]$........
$B \backslash A =[x: x \in B \land x \notin A]$
$\lnot ( x \in B \lor (x \notin A )$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We think that the statement of the problem is **wrong**.

As said in the above comments, if we correct it as :

> $(A \backslash B)' \backslash (B \backslash A)' = B \backslash A$

we have that the condition for $(A \backslash B)'$ is :

$\lnot (x \in A \land x \notin B)$, that is (using De Morgan) :

$(x \notin A \lor x \in B)$.

With the same approach, the condition for $(B \backslash A)'$ is :

$(x \notin B \lor x \in A)$.

So the "global" condition becomes :

$(x \notin A \lor x \in B) \land \lnot (x \notin B \lor x \in A)$, that is :

$(x \notin A \lor x \in B) \land (x \in B \land x \notin A)$

Now, going back to set properties, this is :

$(A' \cup B) \cap (A' \cap B)$.

But $(A' \cap B)$ is a subset of $(A' \cup B)$, so that their intersection is $(A' \cap B)$.

Now, $x \in (A' \cap B)$ iff $(x \in B \land x \notin A)$ i.e.

> $x \in B \backslash A$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

- $A\setminus B$ should not be understood as $a - b$, one of the reasons being $(a-b)+b = a$, but $(A \setminus B) \cup B = A \cup B$.
- There is a very useful identity for set difference, namely $$A \setminus B = A \cap B\,', \tag{$\spadesuit$}$$ it is often enough to solve most of this kind of homework-related problems.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: so, I should the identity of $A \backslash B = A \cap B'$ instead. The book mentioned that the $\backslash$ can be read as as minus, but it wouldn't be a great idea.

Comment: @usukidoll You can _read_ "$\setminus$" as "$-$", but it should not be _understood_ as the same thing, these are two different operators with just very similar names. Regarding the identity, you could use it, but you don't have to, there are many ways to solve your problem. On the other hand, set difference operator is often unpleasant to deal with, and substituting it with something more well-behaved might considerably simplify the problem (even if the resulting expression may appear more complex).

Comment: @usukidoll Besides, I think your problem should be $(A \setminus B)' \setminus (B \setminus A)' = B \setminus A$, that is, there should be a negation at $(B \setminus A)$.

Comment: Really? The book displayed $(A \backslash B)'\backslash (B \backslash A) = B \backslash A$

Comment: Translating $A \setminus B$ into $x \in A \land \neg x \in B$ (notice the similarity to $\spadesuit$ and that $x \notin B$ is $\neg x \in B$) you get $\neg (x \in A \land \neg x \in B) \land \neg(x \in B \land \neg x \in A) \iff (x \in B \land \neg x \in A)$ which is just [not true](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B%21+%28a+%26%26+%21+b%29+%26%26+%21%28b+%26%26+%21+a%29%5D+xnor+%5Bb+%26%26+%21a%5D). Compare with [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B%21+%28a+%26%26+%21+b%29+%26%26+%21%21%28b+%26%26+%21+a%29%5D+xnor+%5Bb+%26%26+%21a%5D).

Comment: *(i)* A\B is $x \in A \land x \notin B$, so : (A\B)' is $x \notin A \lor x \in B$. *(ii)* B\A is $x \in B \land x \notin A$. *(iii)* the case $(A \backslash B)' \backslash (B \backslash A)$ is equivalent to say that $x \in$ the first **and** $x \notin$ the second; but $x \notin$ the second is $x \in$ the *complement* of the second; so it must be : $(x \notin A \lor x \in B) \land (x \in A \lor x \notin B)$. Using the distributivity property (if I haven't make a mistake) give us : ... 1/2

Comment: $(x \in A \land x \notin A) \lor (x \in A \land x \in B) \lor (x \in B \land x \notin B) \lor (x \notin A \land x \notin B)$ that is: $\emptyset \lor (A \cap B) \lor \emptyset \lor (A \cap B)'$. So we have : $(A \cap B) \cup (A \cap B)' = U$. We have a problem ... we must try with the proposed correction of the statement of the problem. 2/2